# Disable text selection and copy paste in hybrid app using JS

Tags: cordova, copy, paste, textselection

I am trying to disable text selection and copy paste in phonegap applicaion by using following code.

CSS

```
-webkit-user-select:none;
```

JavaScript

```
$('body').on('cut copy paste',function(e){e.preventDefault();});
```

It works on all OS platforms including adroid 4.4+ but having issues on 4.1 and 4.2. Please Help.

Both doesn't support android 4.1.2 and 4.2.1.

[Tested on Micromax canvas 4 and samsung galaxy s2]

Comment: use simple body{ -webkit-touch-callout: none; -webkit-user-select: none; }

Answer (score 18):

you can use css to do that

```
*
{
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

input
{
-webkit-user-select: auto !important;
-khtml-user-select: auto !important;
-moz-user-select: auto !important;
-ms-user-select: auto !important;
user-select: auto !important;
}
```

found here [Disable Copy and Paste in Phonegap](http://qnimate.com/disable-copy-and-paste-in-phonegap/)

Comment: when I use above code[for android 4.1 and 4.2], inputs placeholder disappears and user unable to enter any value in it.

any other solution for android 4.1 and 4.2

Comment: You'll also want to add textarea to the second style declaration

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution I found and worked, but not through JS. Paste the following code in 
MainActivity.java file

```
super.appView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return true;
            }
});
```

Comment: Using cordova, I got no symbol found for super.appView.setOnLongClickListener